# How do I read hex sequences like xD0 into a C# string?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I am converting a series of strings that are designed to display correctly using a special font into a unicode version that can be used anywhere. It's just a glorified set of string replaces:

```
"e]" -> "ἓ"
```

etc.

I'm reading the text using a streamreader which takes the encoding to be UTF-8. All working well. But there are some characters used to replace the punctuation marks that just aren't working. I can see them as hex sequences in notepad++ (encoding set to UTF-8) but when I read them, they all get reduced down to the same character (the 'cannot display' question mark in the black diamond).

```
StreamReader srnorm = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\bgt.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
string norm = srnorm.ReadLine();
```

Should I be reading it as a binary file and working from there or is my encoding very wrong?

[image]
([Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmJPj.png))
When I read that, I get the following:

> o]j ouvci. mh. �avpo�la,bh| pollaplasi,ona evn tw/| kairw/| tou,tw| kai. evn tw/| aivw/ni tw/| evrcome,nw| zwh.n aivw,nion�

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the Stack Overflow help on asking questions to make sure your question gets the highest probability of getting a good answer. In particular: Code with description is great. Code without description is passable. Description without code is near-useless. Can you edit your question and show us what you are doing?

Comment: Hi @Amadan, I'm not sure what to add. I could show you my streamreader creation and ReadLine() but I don't think it would be that illuminating. I've added the string that results from my ReadLine though.

Comment: Thanks, it's getting clearer (and better safe than sorry). I gather that `bgt.txt` a converted file? `0xCE`, `0xC5` and `0xD0` are not valid UTF-8.

Comment: The source has an option to export to .txt. It also allows for exporting to .rtf which results in sequences like \'c5 in the .rtf file. If it's not valid UTF-8, do I have the wrong encoding?

Comment: Probably wrong encoding, yes. What do you mean by "the source has an option to export..."? How do you generate the file, and what specifies its encoding?

Comment: Your input file is not in UTF-8. Can you show us the original text as it was supposed to look like, so we can guess the correct encoding?

Answer (score 0):

C# strings use UTF-16. This is how they are stored in memory. Because of this you should be able to read the string into memory and replace the characters without any issues. You can then write those characters back to a file (UTF8 is the default character encoding for reading and writing to file if I'm not mistaken). The ?'s just means the console you outputed the string to does not support those characters or the bytes are not of a valid encoding.

Here is [a good article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/strings.aspx) by Jon Skeet about C#/.NET strings.

Comment: Note the binary representation: `0xCE` by itself is a valid character in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: More specifically, if it was UTF-8, it would be the first byte of a two-byte sequence, and the following character would need to be between `0x80` and `0xBF`; but the following character is "a" (`0x61`).

Comment: Does it mean I should be using a BinaryReader rather than trying as text?

Comment: @Amadan What I'm trying to explain to user4147820 is that don't have to read unicode files with binary readers, C# strings can store unicode characters. You just need to be sure that you are reading the file with the proper encoding (and the file isn't corrupted).

Comment: When I read it as UTF-16, all the problem characters are reduced to 0xFF (byte 1: 253, byte 2: 255).

Comment: I was reacting to "The ?'s just means the console you outputed the string to does not support those characters". Your addition of "or the bytes are not of a valid encoding" addresses my complaint, thank you :)

Comment: @Amadan Yeah I added that to clarify, thanks for the comment. user4147820 - strings are stored in memory as UTF-16, this does not mean you read them as UTF-16. You must read them using the encoding that was used to encode them in the first place. As an example, if I write you a message in spanish you MUST translate my message FROM spanish into english (the language used in your memory). Like-wise if text is in a UTF8-encoded file, it must be read as UTF8. UTF8 was designed to be backward compatible with ASCII which is why valid ASCII is also valid UTF8, but this is not true for all non-ASCII.

Comment: @user4147820 ...This is why Joel states in his blog "It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses" This is another great read, http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Despertar: While I agree with the general sentiment, it depends on your language though. In some languages, the internal representation is fixed, and you don't (and shouldn't) care about it. I'd modify his sentence to say "It does not make sense to input or output a string without knowing which encoding you're using".